# invalid initializer in gba

Tags: c, game-boy-advance, devkitpro

im Lino, im new on this community. basically, im trying to save data into the GAMEPAK_RAM of the GBA, and the pointer dont work. the code line is this:

```
#define GAMEPAK_RAM ((volatile uint8_t*)0x0E000000)
```

and the error is this:

```
    In file included from source/main.c:2:0:
source/OpenEngine.h:8:21: error: invalid initializer
 #define GAMEPAK_RAM ((volatile uint8_t*)0x0E000000)
                     ^
```

someone can help me?
if other info is needed,  please tell me

Comment: What's the code where you are using GAMEPAK_RAM?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vcb7DGep

Comment: Your code doesn't define or use GAMEPAK_RAM anywhere so it shouldn't give errors relating to GAMEPAK_RAM.

Comment: ooohhh! i use GAMEPAK_RAM:

Comment: unsigned short *SaveMemory[0xFFFF] = GAMEPAK_RAM;

Comment: here´s the entire code:

Comment: https://github.com/LinoBigatti/homebrew-tests/tree/master/game

Comment: You are supposed to include the *minimal* code needed to exhibit the problem, *in your question*, not as links to off-site resources; please check the Help Centre for more info on how to write a diagnosable, self-contained question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned short *SaveMemory[0xFFFF] = GAMEPAK_RAM;
```

This is the same as:

```
unsigned short *SaveMemory[0xFFFF] = ((volatile uint8_t*)0x0E000000);
```

`SaveMemory` is an array and `((volatile uint8_t*)0x0E000000)` is a pointer. You can't set an array equal to a pointer, hence the error.